# Get all values from a listbox using Coded UI Test and select it

Tags: vb.net, coded-ui-tests

I am using uimap in coded ui test to get information about controlers in an application, the value returned for a listbox is "client" - controlType, technologyname MSAA and Name = session.
My goal is to be able to get all values of a listbox and then select a value using the code.
Is there a way to do that ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the `UITestControl` object for the list box you should be able to get all list entries by using the `GetChildren` method. It returns a collection having all the child controls of the parent control. Depending on the *exact* structure of your list box and its contents, you may need to call the method repeatedly to get the grandchild or deeper controls.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getchildren.aspx

**Update**

In C# you might write code based on the following:

```
foreach (UITestControl child in parent.GetChildren()) {
    if ( someTestOfTheControl(child) ) {
        ... process the child control here ...
    }
}
```

Or possibly on

```
foreach (UITestControl child in parent.GetChildren()) {
    foreach (UITestControl grandChild in child.GetChildren()) {
        if ( someTestOfTheControl(grandChild) ) {
            ... process the grandChild control here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Where `someTestOfTheControl()` tests whether the control is the one you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried this code but i get an error

Comment: Hello AdrianHHH please see my question below , thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using UIMap - Get the control of ListBox

**ItemToSelect** - Is the name of item in string

```
WinList ListControl = new WinList(Control);
string[] CompleteList = ListControl.GetContent();
        CompleteList = CompleteList.Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
        string Value = CompleteList.First(x => x.Contains(ItemToSelect));
        Mouse.Click((WinListItem)ListControl.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains(Value)));
```